# VSCode - Change the background color of active item in explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanted to change the background color of the selected file in explorer in VS code and I found this setting `list.activeSelectionBackground` which you can see in the picture actually worked.

[image]

But the problem is that it only works when I click on the file explicitly but it doesn't when I switch to a different file using `Alt+tab`, then it looses the background color even when actually the file is selected in explorer.

After `Alt+tab` it starts showing the selection background like this, which is the default way

[image]

I tried some other settings like `list.inactiveFocusBackground` and `list.focusBackground` but they didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#fff",
  "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#fff"
}
```

Just set them to the same thing so whether that Explorer item selection is active or not it will appear the same.